# sorting map in flutter

Tags: flutter, sorting, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying to sort the below map into key:value format displayed on a card widget. The entire numeric key should be sorted in ascending order and all the alpha keys should be
sorted in ASCII, ascending order.

```
Dictionary = {'34': 'thirty-four', '90': 'ninety',
'91': 'ninety-one''21': 'twenty-one',
'61': 'sixty-one', '9': 'nine',
'2': 'two', '6': 'six', '3': 'three',
'8': 'eight', '80': 'eighty', '81': 'eighty-one',
'Ninety-Nine': '99', 'nine-hundred': '900'}
```

I would appreciate help on the best way to approach this problem

Comment: Sorting an array a map?

Comment: What was your expected output?

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil i want to display the information in key: value format using a listview

Answer (score 1):

This solution worked for me.

```
  void sortMethod() {
    var dict = {
      '34': 'thirty-four',
      '90': 'ninety',
      '91': 'ninety-one',
      '21': 'twenty-one',
      '61': 'sixty-one',
      '9': 'nine',
      '2': 'two',
      '6': 'six',
      '3': 'three',
      '8': 'eight',
      '80': 'eighty',
      '81': 'eighty-one',
      'Ninety-Nine': '99',
      'nine-hundred': '900'
    };

    // Extracting the keys of the dict into a list
    var keys = dict.keys.toList();
    const int maxValue = 9999999;
    //sorting the list of keys
    keys.sort((k1, k2) {
      int k1Int = maxValue;
      int k2Int = maxValue;
      try{
        k1Int= int.parse(k1);
      } on FormatException {
      }
      try{
        k2Int= int.parse(k2);
      } on FormatException {
      }
      return k1Int.compareTo(k2Int);
    });

    //iterating the keys in sorted order and printing the key value pair
    for (var key in keys) {
      print('$key : ${dict[key]}');
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope its help to you.

**Your Map**

```
static var dictionary = {
    '34': 'thirty-four',
    '90': 'ninety',
    '91': 'ninety-one',
    '21': 'twenty-one',
    '61': 'sixty-one',
    '9': 'nine',
    '2': 'two',
    '6': 'six',
    '3': 'three',
    '8': 'eight',
    '80': 'eighty',
    '81': 'eighty-one',
    '99': '  Ninety-Nine',
    '900': '  Nine-hundred',
  };
```

**Sorting Function:**

```
  var sortedKeys = dictionary.values.toList()..sort();

  final sorted = Map.fromEntries(
    dictionary.entries.toList()
      ..sort(
        (e1, e2) => e1.key.compareTo(e2.key),
      ),
  );
```

**Your Widget:**

```
ListView.builder(
      itemCount: sorted.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        String key = sorted.keys.elementAt(index);
        return new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            new ListTile(
              leading: new Text("$key"),
              title: new Text("${sorted[key]}"),
            ),
            new Divider(
              height: 2.0,
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    ),
```

Full Example Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  static var dictionary = {
    '34': 'thirty-four',
    '90': 'ninety',
    '91': 'ninety-one',
    '21': 'twenty-one',
    '61': 'sixty-one',
    '9': 'nine',
    '2': 'two',
    '6': 'six',
    '3': 'three',
    '8': 'eight',
    '80': 'eighty',
    '81': 'eighty-one',
    '99': '  Ninety-Nine',
    '900': '  Nine-hundred',
  };

  var sortedKeys = dictionary.values.toList()..sort();

  final sorted = Map.fromEntries(
    dictionary.entries.toList()
      ..sort(
        (e1, e2) => e1.key.compareTo(e2.key),
      ),
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(dictionary);
    print(sortedKeys);
    print(sorted);
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: sorted.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        String key = sorted.keys.elementAt(index);
        return new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            new ListTile(
              leading: new Text("$key"),
              title: new Text("${sorted[key]}"),
            ),
            new Divider(
              height: 2.0,
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Test above code [here](https://dartpad.dev/?null_safety=true&id)

Result Screen -> [image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way that you can do that.

```
import 'dart:collection';

void main() {
  Map<String, String> dictionary = {
    '34': 'thirty-four',
    '90': 'ninety',
    '91': 'ninety-one',
    '21': 'twenty-one',
    '61': 'sixty-one',
    '9': 'nine',
    '2': 'two',
    '6': 'six',
    '3': 'three',
    '8': 'eight',
    '80': 'eighty',
    '81': 'eighty-one',
    'Ninety-Nine': '99',
    'nine-hundred': '900'
  };

  final SplayTreeMap<String, String> st = SplayTreeMap<String, String>();

  st.addAll(dictionary);

  st.forEach((k, v) => {
        if (isNumeric(k, v))
          {print("$k : ${st[k]}")}
        else
          {print("$v : ${st[k]}")}
      });
}

bool isNumeric(String k, String v) {
  if (k == null) {
    return false;
  }
  if (int.tryParse(k) == null) {
    return int.parse(v) != null;
  }
  return int.parse(k) != null;
}
```